# fractional derivative in mathematica/ maple ?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, maple, fractals, derivative

Any build-in function to calculate fractional derivatives in Mathematica or Maple ?

What method does it use for the derivation ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

From the Notebook from the [Fractional Derivatives page of MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalDerivative.html), this *Mathematica* code:

```
FractionalD[nu_, f_, t_, opts___] := 
  Integrate[(t - x)^(-nu - 1) (f /. t -> x), {x, 0, t}, opts]/Gamma[-nu]

FractionalD[mu_?Positive, f_, t_, opts___] :=
  Module[{m = Ceiling[mu]},
    D[FractionalD[-(m - mu), f, t, opts], {t, m}]
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

In Maple, see the help-page for the command [fracdiff](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=fracdiff), which describes its available methods.